# calculating hosts using 1 network address

Tags: hosts, subnet

[image: The Image is here of calculating the host]

[image: Image of the whole network]

IP and/or subnet mask is not allowed for use on a port

Did I do it right?

I think there is something wrong

```
HOST    BB  NSM DELTA   Octet   NA           FUH            LUH            BA
510     9   23  2        3rd    120.0.0.0    120.0.0.1      120.0.1.254   120.0.1.255
500     9   23  2        3rd    120.0.2.0    120.0.2.1      120.0.3.254   120.0.3.255
128     8   24  1        3rd    120.0.4.0    120.0.4.1      120.0.4.254   120.0.4.255
115     7   25  128      4th    120.0.5.0    120.0.5.1      120.0.5.126   120.0.5.127
110     7   25  128      4th    120.0.5.128  120.0.5.129    120.0.5.144   120.0.5.145
90      7   25  128      4th    120.0.5.146  120.0.5.147    120.0.5.245   120.0.5.246
80      7   25  128      4th    120.0.5.247  120.0.5.248    120.0.6.81    120.0.6.82
60      6   26  64       4th    120.0.6.83   120.0.6.84     120.0.6.145   120.0.6.146
40      6   26  64       4th    120.0.6.147  120.0.6.148    120.0.6.161   120.0.6.162
30      5   27  32       4th    120.0.6.163  120.0.6.164    120.0.6.193   120.0.6.194
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.6.195  120.0.6.196    120.0.6.197   120.0.6.198
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.6.199  120.0.6.200    120.0.6.201   120.0.6.202
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.6.203  120.0.6.204    120.0.6.205   120.0.6.206
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.6.207  120.0.6.208    120.0.6.209   120.0.6.210
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.6.211  120.0.6.212    120.0.6.213   120.0.6.214
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.6.215  120.0.6.216    120.0.6.217   120.0.6.218
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.6.219  120.0.6.220    120.0.6.221   120.0.6.222
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.6.223  120.0.6.224    120.0.6.225   120.0.6.226
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.6.227  120.0.6.228    120.0.6.229   120.0.6.230
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.6.231  120.0.6.232    120.0.6.233   120.0.6.234
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.6.235  120.0.6.236    120.0.6.237   120.0.6.238
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.6.239  120.0.6.240    120.0.6.241   120.0.6.242
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.6.243  120.0.6.244    120.0.6.245   120.0.6.246
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.6.247  120.0.6.248    120.0.6.249   120.0.6.250
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.6.251  120.0.6.252    120.0.6.214   120.0.6.215
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.6.216  120.0.6.217    120.0.6.253   120.0.6.254
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.6.255  120.0.7.0      120.0.7.2     120.0.7.3
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.7.4    120.0.7.5      120.0.7.6     120.0.7.7
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.7.8    120.0.7.9      120.0.7.10    120.0.7.11
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.7.12   120.0.7.13     120.0.7.14    120.0.7.15
2       2   30  4        4th    120.0.7.16   120.0.7.17     120.0.7.18    120.0.7.19
```

Comment: You seem to have a good idea on what you're doing, so I don't want to spoil the answers and learning for you, yet. I'll give you a hint though, look at row 5, where you have 110 hosts. Your LUH and BA are way off. Then it went downhill from there. Do some fixing if you know how. Otherwise @ me and I'll help you out

Comment: I love you man... thank you so much... @DrZoo